# Load YAML fixture for Map<Enum,Integer>

Tags: java, playframework, yaml, snakeyaml

Trying to load up some fixture data in Play! 1.2.4 with SnakeYAML. Object type is `Map<enum, Integer>`. Error I am getting on Fixtures.loadModels("quest.yml") is "Cannot load fixture quests.yml: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum".

Code snippets-

```
Constants.java
public enum STATS {
        CREATIVITY, ENTHUSIASM, ...
}

Quest.java
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Map<Constants.STATS, Integer> reward;

quest.yml
Quest(sirlin):
    reward:
        CREATIVITY: 1
```

As you can see, I've specified that I want to use the String value of the enum STATS with @MapKeyEnumerated annotation. I'm not sure how to change format of yml definition to get this working correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: I have found [this test cases](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/source/browse/src/test/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/EnumTest.java?name=v1.0.1&r=2ce78be1172188f4ea505cbd7b947a30c6a02e96), but when I use them I get the following error `exception=Class not found: models.EnumClass`. I'm with the same problem ^.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have found a 'solution' for play 1.2.4, it's ugly, but it works.

The first thing I found was [this test case](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/source/browse/src/test/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/EnumTest.java?name=v1.0.1&r=2ce78be1172188f4ea505cbd7b947a30c6a02e96), that shows how it is you should do it:

```
map:
  !!org.pacakge.EnumClass 'CLUBS': 1
  !!org.pacakge.EnumClass 'DIAMONDS': 2
```

That would give a map with enums as keys.

But it doesn't work as it gives this exception:

```
Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:models.Plazos; exception=Class not found: org.pacakge.EnumClass
```

But then I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/quvqlk1YutI/fSG2rB2BeS0J) and [this](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/constructing-an-instance-of-a-class-with-snakeyaml.4153/). The problem happens because the Yaml parser (snakeyaml) creates its own ClassLoader in order to parse a .yml file. The structure of the Play! framework uses its own ClassLoader. The solution would be to replace this

```
Yaml y = new Yaml();
```

with this

```
Yaml y = new Yaml(new CustomClassLoaderConstructor(playClassLoader));
```

but, of course, that is being done inside the `play.test.Fixtures` class, so what was my solution? Well, copy that class into your project and replace in the method `loadModels` this line:

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
```

with this one:

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new CustomClassLoaderConstructor(Play.classloader));
```

And that will make it work.

Comment: Hum, I have the same problem, and stumbled upon the same links, but I tried it with play 2.0 and I keep getting the same Class not found exception : 
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new CustomClassLoaderConstructor(Play.application().classloader())); 
Does it work for you in play 2.0.2 ?

Comment: No, sorry I didn't put it in the answer, this worked for me in play 1.2.4. I'll edit the answer now.